# Raspberry Pi — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

Can you find your name on the first two pages [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)? If so, brace yourself for some good news! *{obligatory pie/pi pun or pie-related joke here}*
We wanna send you a little package, as a token of our appreciation for helping this site and community grow into what it is today! Inside this little box, you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!]

**A MAGNETIC PICK-UP TOOL!**

[image: MAGNETIC PICK-UP TOOL!!!!!!!!!!]

I'll be reaching out to you later today with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such! <sub><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub>[There's plenty of pie left... ʱªʱªʱª (ᕑᗢूᓫ∗)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwWhe.jpg)</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sub>

**Thanks to all of you for making this site awesome!**

Comment: Thanks for the swag! Now I'll have to forget this on purpose so I'll get surprised when it gets here.

Comment: Sweet! Can't wait!

Comment: The picture of the Pie made me hungry

Comment: You hint at "events and such" care to elaborate?

Comment: Wow! Thanks guys! I haven't been as active as I was a while back because of projects and school, but wow :D Can't wait!

Comment: @PatrickCook [Stuff like conferences, hackatons, and stuff of the like.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132282/208518)

Comment: The first user on 3rd page has _only_ 1 reputation less than the last user on 2nd page. Ouch :)

Comment: Is the T-shirt "one-size-fits-no-one"?  I know where I want to put an RPi sticker - but the magnetic pick-up tool won't help with that!  @PandaLion98 - I hate to think what the postage will be to Antarctica for yours!

Comment: @SlySven I think you had to fill in a form. You can pick your size there. The form also included a T-shirt size guide: https://districtclothing.com/fit-guide/

Comment: @OP What happens if I fill in the form twice?

Comment: @PandaLion98 I'll purge the duplicate entries ;)

Comment: @SlySven If you received the link to the form, you'll find a fitting guide there.

Comment: @SlySven Where do you want to put the RPi sticker?

Comment: @OP There's plenty of pie left... ʱªʱªʱª (ᕑᗢूᓫ∗)

Comment: @PandaLion98 - nowhere *too* extreme - on the box for my [Home Automation](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/675/36970) system when I put it all together... 8-/

Comment: @SlySven Ha, I'm putting mine on my project too!

Comment: How do I contact you about the delivery details? Essentially I'd like fedex to call me 30 mins prior to delivery so I can go home and wait for delivery from my workplace, thanks

Comment: You can contact me directly by e-mail, @EdChum.

Comment: was the swag dispatched already? Haven't received mine yet.I got a mail and filled the form though.

Comment: This swag was shipped out yesterday!

Comment: Wow, quick shipping, I just received mine! Thank you so much! Can't seem to get the led on the tool working though. The shirt it really nice, can't wait to show it off to my friends!

Comment: Didn't realize the sizes were different. It's pretty big. Will probably use the shirt as pajamas instead. Unless

Comment: Got mine in the UK and looks/fits great! Love the light in the magnetic pick-up.

Comment: I recently got my swag, but today was the 1st day it has been warm enough to wear a T-shirt. The logo and Rasperry PI banner is in the middle of my stomach (most T-shirts have the slogan at mid chest - nipple level). This is not thee most flattering position, or is it some kind of in-joke about "berries inside"?